# how much does it cost to build an O'Neill cylinder?

Tags: science-based

how much does it cost to build an O'Neill cylinder? 
I mean only how much will its materials (steel, fuel and all useful mass) weigh?

O'Neill's cylinder (island 3) was two very large, rotating in opposite directions, cylinders, each 5 miles (8 kilometers) in diameter and 20 miles (32 kilometers) in length, connected to each other by rods through the system bearings. By rotating, they create artificial gravity on their inner surface due to centrifugal force.

How much steel tone is needed to build such a colossus? After all, the thickness of the cylinder cylinder will probably be about 7 meters

Comment: If you know the thickness of the cylinder walls then the problem is already solved, isn't it? (And I am certain there is a serious error in your calculations. At 7 meters, that's not a load bearing structure, that's greatly overengineered armor; and anyway, engineers very much prefer [trusses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss) of steel over solid pieces. Trusses are very very much lighter at the same strength: which is to say, the walls will certainly be a lattice of interconnected rods, not a gigantic solid cast piece.)

Comment: According to [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/news/background/facts/astp.html) it currently costs $10,000 per pound to put mass into orbit. The rest is just maths.

Comment: I have just engage some experts to source for steel in space so I'll get back to you shortly...

Comment: Ugh. I don’t need to look for something in space! I need to know HOW MUCH MATERIALS TO construction ? How many materials do I need in kilograms ?!

Comment: Oh I see, then it becomes easier and as AlexP commented just punch in the numbers for volume and multiply by density of steel assuming it is one piece instead of trusses.

Comment: Well and how much approximately it turned out, the data concerning the cylinder О Nile ( island 3 ) are upstairs

Comment: I'm now voting to close as the title of the question seems entirely orthogonal to what you _actually_ want, and what you appear to want is only listed in comments and not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**I've been pondering this for a while. I think the better question would be how to achieve it first, and work back to costs.**

It is not acheivable using current methods of production and construction. Our current methods are:

1. Design it
2. Tender it to contractors
3. Build it using their standards
4. Inspect it to be ready for use

None of the above is possible as:

1. There are no precedents to use to design it and I believe the calculation capacity and complexity of the structural, life support, materials and so on are too much for 'hand' done design.
2. Traditional procurement methods like costing or tendering won't work as there are no precedents
3. There are no standards, and building (even with a few machines on-site) is still essentially 'by hand' even in today's world.
4. Risk - no-one can say it won't explode, or depressurise

So I think we need to do the following in sequence:

1. Develop a business case for it that provides return on investment
2. Find an asteroid to turn into an O'Neil cylinder
3. Develop an AI to design it in the most optimum fashion possible, ie. minimal effort, minimal fuel, minimal structural requirements, no waste, no imported materials
4. Develop bots to construct it, and develop a factory to build the bots - no way this can be done by human hands, it must be FULLY automated
5. Wait till the AI finishes, and test it with bots before humans are put in a risky situation

Now for cost - it is unable to be costed except the development of AI and bot technology. If done traditionally I would think at least a trillion is a start, however if fully automated perhaps this could come down to 100 billion or so. However, AI could work at this and if you have some time, and a factory to build bots for you, perhaps at least a billion? Add perhaps an 'Elon' factor and maybe it could be less - you never know the possibilities of entrepreneurship.

Comment: At our current technological status, why would any remotely conceivable AI be better than a skilled team of humans at designing an O'Neil cylinder? For instance, flying to the moon was something that had no precedent or standards, yet humans managed to make it happen.

Comment: Gentlemen, I already know what you just said. I am "not interested" in the cost and automatic Assembly process ( in building my world, this cylinder will be secretly created by some organization on the Lagrange point at Titan, a satellite of Saturn. The story takes place today, and this organization does not yet have the technical capabilities to move between Saturn and the Asteroid belt.) I'm only interested in the weight of the materials, how much for example a ton of aluminum is needed to make it? ( cost and risk are unimportant, they work for free )

Comment: O'Neill's cylinder (island 3) was two very large, rotating in opposite directions, cylinders, each 5 miles (8 kilometers) in diameter and 20 miles (32 kilometers) in length, connected to each other by rods through the system bearings. By rotating, they create artificial gravity on their inner surface due to centrifugal force.
 After all, the thickness of the cylinder cylinder will probably be about 7 meters

Comment: @FrenchThompson if you were "not interested" then you should say so, very clearly, in your question. If you didn't care about the cost, and only cared about the mass, why is your question entitled **how much does it cost to build an O'Neill cylinder**? Now you have multiple answers, it is too late to reasonable edit your question. Perhaps you should ask a new one, simply about how much an Island Three would weigh.

Comment: I asked my (not-yet-public) home AI... it said the project wasn’t particularly interesting and declined to help you. It did say that if you want a habitat without air or any containment requirements populated entirely by robots, then it would be happy to direct our activities to make that happen.

Comment: @BBeast : Yeah. I'd think AI would be more useful for running automated construction robots (e.g. to mine asteroids and assemble the construct), if anything.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Actually, in reflection, I think there is a space for AI in the design phase. Not for designing the *entire* thing, but rather for optimising individual pieces by means of machine learning. Machine learning is already applicable to materials sciences and various optimisation problems. But this is perhaps different to what the answer suggests. In what I just described AI would be used as a design tool rather than doing the designing per se. Then there would be different AI used for mining, construction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult question to answer... like trying to ballpark the cost of developing an atomic bomb prior to the Manhattan project, or asking Tsiolkovsky how much a moon landing might cost. We don't have all the technologies we need yet, and we certainly don't have the required expertise. More importantly, we haven't even tried any intermediate steps... there's a lot of scope for more achievable designs between the ISS and a cavernous space city.

Island Three (the classic cylinder) is so far out of reach it seems barely worth thinking about. Island One, a much more modestly sized habitat is a more sensible design to consider. It is an evolution of the Bernal Sphere design so the actual habitable area is a sphere, but you can handwave that as a sort of really short cylinder with round endcaps.

I'm not sure how much O'Neill thought it would cost, but NASA's Ames research centre reckoned something like 140 billion dollars in the mid 70s, so maybe 700-800 billion nowadays. [A more recent source](https://www.thespacereview.com/article/1238/1) suggests that it would really cost as much as 10 *trillion* dollars now. I suspect they may even be a bit over-optimistic. O'Neill's original work presupposed much cheaper spaceflight and a much more mature human presence in space and on the Moon, and being in the position to build industrial facilities on the moon sounds like a multiple-trillion-dollar project in itself and it is but a step on the way to building O'Neill's islands.

Island Three is so much more vast and ambitious and complex than Island One that it probably doesn't even make sense to price it in modern currency, because it simply couldn't be created by the current world economy.

> How much steel tone is needed to build such a colossus?

The Stanford Torus design, which was designed as an improvement over O'Neill's original Island One design (the [whole Stanford Torus document is available online](https://space.nss.org/settlement/nasa/75SummerStudy/Design.html) in various forms, and might be worth a read) required [10 million tonnes of Lunar regolith](https://space.nss.org/settlement/nasa/75SummerStudy/figure1.2.gif) from which useful metals could be be extracted. About 30% by mass of regolith is metal...half of that is iron, and the rest is useful stuff like titanium, aluminium and magnesium, so there was no need to use steel for everything even back when the designs were first proposed. The much newer [Kalpana One](https://space.nss.org/kalpana-one-space-settlement/) design used something like 7 million tonnes of material for shielding, though the linked paper doesn't go into detail as to how much of that was also used for structural purposes. Larger habitats, such as Island Three, would be about three orders of magnitude larger, but lets not run before we can walk, eh?

> After all, the thickness of the cylinder cylinder will probably be about 7 meters

More like four, but the correct solution is to not use 1970s materials and engineering to build your space habitat. Modern plastics and composites and alloys are pretty good, and remember that the original work was done fifty years ago. Moreover the design is perhaps a little inefficient. There's plenty of alternatives that need less air, less massively overbuilt shells and may avoid other inconvenient issues like coriolis winds forming in the habitat.

Comment: Which of the modern (available for sale to ordinary people) types of plastics can be suitable for creating a structure like Kalpan 1 and how many approximately materials in kilograms will be needed?
Kalpana 1:
Diameter: 1570 meters
Width: 325 meters

Comment: @FrenchThompson the comment section of an answer on a closed question is probably not the best place to ask that sort of thing ;-) But composites are the way to go. Using large quantities of UHMWPE where practical is probably desirable, due to its high strength and toughness and its usefulness as shielding against particle radiation. It won't be sufficient on its own for various material reasons, so backing it up with other things will be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

## About $852,000,000,000,000,000

Source:  https://www.forbes.com/sites/carolpinchefsky/2012/02/21/how-much-would-it-cost-to-build-the-death-star-from-star-wars/#3abab0147c73

The number is obviously wrong for your project.
At 140km in diameter (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star), a 1st gen Death Star is much larger than your O'Neill cylinder.  You could probably make at least 10 000 of them at that price. (1436753 km^3 vs 108 km^3).

Comment: An answer that the answerer admits is obviously wrong is not really very helpful, is it?

Comment: Yes. Question, answers can be deleted? (only this one, it’s just like a "eyesore")

Comment: @FrenchThompson yes, there's a little link at the bottom of each post marked `flag`. You should be able to see that (it needs at least 15 points). Click it, and it'll be raised as needing more attention, and it might get deleted if enough users think it deserves it.